# encrypt password - Connect Dreamweaver to SQL server databse

Tags: sql, dreamweaver, password-encryption

I am trying to set a connection between Dreamweaver and Sql server database,
i am using the wizard under Dreamweaver CS3
the wizard creates a file named connections and inside that file i have

```
<%
' FileName="Connection_ado_conn_string.htm"
' Type="ADO"
' DesigntimeType="ADO"
' HTTP="false"
' Catalog=""
' Schema=""
Dim MM_Q_S_Conn_STRING

MM_Q_S_Conn_STRING = "Driver={SQL Server};ServeR=\SQL08R2T_INST4;Database=XTEST;Uid=                TDWEAVER;Pwd=tdweaver;"
%>
```

all is working fine and i can access the database and add/delete/update records

The administrator is asking to apply encryption to the password and send him the way the  encryption is performed

Can i add encryption to the password inside the Connection String? or maybe add encryption type ?
Any help please

Comment: Duplicate of http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/22817/how-to-encrypt-database-connection-credentials-on-a-web-server

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My first question would be: Does the driver encrypt the connection to the database? If not, then what's the point of encrypting the password when the first connection publishes it as plain text on the local network?

The next question: Why can anyone read the file? If only the process can read the file, what additional security does encrypting the password provide?

For me, this feels like [security by obscurity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Security_through_obscurity) which is [a valid security layer if you have covered all the other bases](https://danielmiessler.com/study/security_and_obscurity/). If you didn't, then it's just a waste of time.

Comment: this file is accessible from many persons, the administrator gave me the username and password to add it to the string, he provided it in plain text, now he is asking to encrypt this password and send it back with the encryption method, excuse me for my zero knowledge in encryption/connections

Comment: If he gave the password to you by mail, then 50% of all criminals on the planet already know the password ;-) Short answer to your plight: This is a complex topic and unless you know exactly what you're doing, there are many ways to do it wrong which means: You will feel safe but you won't be. My current feeling is that neither you nor your administrator know enough about this. I could be wrong though, so you should discuss this with him; maybe he has a solution but thought that you already know.